# Inconsistent character spacing with rust-skia

Tags: skia

I'm trying to render some text with rust-skia, but the result has the
[inconsistent spacing between character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM3eE.png).
Here's my code snippet:

```rust
...
let font = skia_safe::Font::default();
let paint = skia_safe::Paint::default();

let text = "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD";
let origin = skia_safe::Point::new(20., 20.);
canvas.draw_str(text, origin, &font, &paint);
```

What should i do to get the consistent character spacing.